# How to send Text with Special Characters via HTML Form?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to send code (text containing special characters) from a user input with a classic HTML `Form` to a backend server.

Let's say the provided code (text) by the user is:

```js
console.log("one big pizza, please");
```

Inside my script running on the client's side I have access to the user's input. I then intercept the Form submit like this:

```js
document.querySelector("#submit-form")
    .addEventListener("submit", this.handleSubmit.bind(this), false);

handleSubmit(event) {
    const code = this.code;
    console.log(code); /* console.log("one big pizza, please"); */
    event.target.innerHTML += `<input name="code" type="hidden" value="${code}">`;
}
```

The problem is that only the first part until the first `"` quotation mark gets submitted. So the string gets cut off at its usually natural ending mark. I've then tried to use `JSON.stringify` but the result is the same. Although printing the outcome of JSON.stringify to the console shows that the special characters seem to get escaped properly:

```js
"console.log(\"one big pizza, please\");"
```

the Form data in the body of the Post request for the code field is still cut off:

```js
code: "console.log("
```

My question is:
How can I get a piece of text containing special characters properly send by an HTML Form to a backend server?

Comment: Create the new content as an Element object, set its propertties, then append that to the DOM directly, instead of hacking together a string which has issues with string delimiters.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest finding an alternative method to adding data to a form than appending a hidden element in the submit handler, as that's a very brittle approach. Depending on when `this.code` is set/updated, you could create the element at that point and not have to worry about creating a submit event handler at all.

Comment: Hi @RoryMcCrossan, the user interacts with an editor, so I have to request the user input from this editor directly. I then have the input inside a variable and am free from here to do whatever I want. I thougth taking the code and sending it directly through a form would be a proper way. What is the benefit of creating an element, appending it to the DOM so that the form can grab it, when there might be a direct solution? Or is there no straight way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Well, I've tried your suggestion and added by default a hidden `input` field to the form which I then fill by setting its `value` property via JS. This seems to work as expected. If this is the way to go I  can live with it ;). Many thanks for your help.

Comment: _"Although printing the outcome of JSON.stringify to the console shows that the special characters seem to get escaped properly"_ - preceding a character with a backslash is escaping that works in JavaScript - but the _context_ you have your problem with there, is not JavaScript, it is HTML.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of appending HTML to the form via JavaScript, add the hidden input element, without a value, to your HTML page. Then in the event handler, set only the value:

```
document.querySelector("#submit-form")
    .addEventListener("submit", this.handleSubmit.bind(this), false);

handleSubmit(event) {
    const code = this.code;
    console.log(code);
    event.target.elements.code.value = code;
}
```